# How to get blog entries from blog namespace show on a DokuWiki start page

Tags: php, dokuwiki

A while back I even created a dokuwiki plugin.

How do I get blog entries from the "blog" namespace shown on my start page?

Does anyone know that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `{{blog>:blog}}` should do the trick ...